# Lock password database

Tags: linux, qnx, momentics

When I try to set root password for QNX, I get the following error:

```
unable to lock password database (No such file or directory)
```

I am currently working on a system builder project where I am trying to configure it to solve this image problem. My target is a PowerPC board. What parts should I check and change?

Answer (score 0):

I think most of your issues are related to Image Filesystem. You trying to use 'passwd' tool but it requires many files (see documentation on QNX site).
Better way is to use qnx6fs somehow that your root dir will be mounted as qnx6 partition.